# Why Android Market App is needed for C2DM services?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am currently working with C2DM services for my android app. I came into these questions,

1. Why Android Market App is needed for C2DM Service?
2. Is C2DM using long polling?
3. Is any other messaging services available other than C2DM?
4. Can I get the time of message arrival?

Plz clarify these. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. C2DM does not need Market App, but it needs Google Talk App, - they just go together with market in all oficial android phones.
2. I don't know
3. There is SMS for example :) Any third-part messaging systems need to be installed, and as I know there is not any popular system
4. in `onReceive()` method just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` - this is quite exactly time of message.(If you are writing app for time-synchronizing using such method or C2DM is not the best idea :)

Answer (score 0):

1. It is antyspam policy.
2. No. it uses push.
3. No. Yoe can implement own service based on long living requests.
4. Yes. You can save time in message receiver.

See this tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#c2dm

Comment: Thanks for reply. Iam already following vogella's tutorial. Can you explain the purpose of following in manifest.xml:   
<permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />               In google code they are saying "Only this application can receive the messages and registration result". But how android maps the messages to my recevier. What if an another appication is registered for c2dm messages? Perhaps my understanding about <permission> is wrong. plz help.